# python reading files

Tags: python, file

I need to get a specific line number from a file that I am passing into a python program I wrote. I know that the line I want will be line 5, so is there a way I can just grab line 5, and not have to iterate through the file?

Comment: Unless you know the specific buffer position of line 5, you _must_ iterate through lines 1-4 to reach line 5. This is because lines are determined by the presence of newlines `\n` within the file.  Is this what you are asking? Or do you mean, that you don't want to load the _entire_ file in order to retrieve line 5?

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many bytes you have before the line you're interested in, you could `seek` to that point and read out a line. Otherwise, a "line" is not a first class construct (it's just a list of characters terminated by a character you're assigning a special meaning to - a newline). To find these newlines, you have to read the file in.

Practically speaking, you could use the `readline` method to read off 5 lines and then read your line.

Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: some project I need to do for my AI class. Basically, I'm being passed a text file, and I know that the line 5 contains the number of blocks for my solver. It is essentially a program that converts a text file to a SAT instance.

Comment: That's fine. Why do you *need* to skip lines till the 5th. What's wrong with reading and discarding them?

Comment: I could do that.. I just need to be able to get whatever is on the 5th line.

Answer (score 3):

you can to use [linecache](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html)

```
import linecache
get = linecache.getline
print(get(path_of_file, number_of_line))
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the module. Although I'm not sure it solves the problem here.

Comment: see my example and see the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think following should do :

```
line_number=4

# Avoid reading the whole file
f = open('path/to/my/file','r')
count=1
for i in f.readline():
    if count==line_number:
        print i
        break
    count+=1

# By reading the whole file
f = open('path/to/my/file','r')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
print lines[line_number-1]     # Index starts from 0
```

This should give you the 4th line in the file.

Comment: this looks like it would work, but I need to grab the file passed in from the command line... so something like
    python myprogram blocks.txt

and I need to grab the 5th line from blocks.txt

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it would read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Fixed.. by adding the other waay.

Comment: In the first case, you are reading the first 4 lines (although not using them) using `readline` (also, you can say `for i in f`). In the second case, you're reading the entire file into memory and then "parsing" it for newlines which is probably not a good idea.